# how to xml schema using xsd validator for inner text?

Tags: xml-parsing, xsd-validation

i have a xml file with schema as below . i generated a xsd validation file to validate .and now i want to add a validation that  the inner text of the  element Tickettype can be empty . also how can i do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AppStatusDetails>
  <Patronid>G5032788W</Patronid>
  <PatronidType>1</PatronidType>
  <Birthdate>19870716</Birthdate>
  <Tickettype>49</Tickettype>
</AppStatusDetails>
```

and i have a xsd validator file as below to validate the xml schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="AppStatusDetails">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Patronid" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="PatronidType" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element name="Birthdate" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
        <xs:element name="Tickettype" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

now what attribuet shoudi have to add to xsd to make the inner text of  ticket type to be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can add `nillable="true"` to the XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="AppStatusDetails">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Patronid" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="PatronidType" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element name="Birthdate" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
        <xs:element name="Tickettype" type="xs:unsignedByte" nillable="true"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**And then `xsi:nil="true"` to `Tickettype` in the document instance:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AppStatusDetails xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Patronid>G5032788W</Patronid>
  <PatronidType>1</PatronidType>
  <Birthdate>19870716</Birthdate>
  <Tickettype xsi:nil="true"></Tickettype>
</AppStatusDetails>
```